# Matching a pattern from list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am working with a list of lists and I want to match patterns in lists. For instance, I have shown a list of lists below.

```
 x = [[['a', 5],
      ['b', 0.11],
      ['c', 0.85]]
     [['a', 'b', 0.5],
      ['b', 'c', 1.0],
      ['c', 'a', 0.7]],
     [['a', 'b', 'c', 0.9],
      ['b', 'c', 'a', 0.4],
      ['a', 'c', 'b', 1.0]]]
```

Now I want to give an input like ("a","b","c") then it should give me respective value ex. 0.9 in above list.

I tried to use

```
 if ["a","b","c"] in x : 
>>> False.
```

But it is not working that way. How can I solve this ? Please suggest any solution.

Aditya.

Comment: Seems that is a list of list of list, 3 level

Comment: yes....it is list of lists of lists

Comment: Maybe you need a different data structure, e.g.: a dictionary with keys as your 'abc' sequences? x = {'a': 5, 'b': 0.11, ..., 'abc': 0.9, ... }. 'abc' in x will give True and x['abc'] will return 0.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
x = [
     [['a', 5],['b', 0.11],['c', 0.85]],
     [['a', 'b', 0.5],['b', 'c', 1.0],['c', 'a', 0.7]],
     [['a', 'b', 'c', 0.9],['b', 'c', 'a', 0.4],['a', 'c', 'b', 1.0]]]

checklist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

return_value = [j[-1]   for i in x for j in i if j[:-1] == checklist][0]
print(return_value)

>> 0.9
```

with this code, you can find any pattern that exists by changing checklist like `checklist = ['a']` output will be `5`

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not hashable, you need to use `tuple`:

```
xx = {tuple(a[:-1]):a[-1]  for b in x for a in b}

if ('a','b','c') in xx: print(xx[('a','b','c')])
# 0.9
```

Comment: There is no explanation at all of what is the intermediate structure you use

Answer (score 0):

The first thought would be to check that all elements of the input are in the subsublist, like this

```
value = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for sublist in x:
    for part in sublist:
        if all(v in part for v in value):
            print(part)
```

Or setting the value as a `set` you can check `issubset`

```
value = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for sublist in x:
    for part in sublist:
        if value.issubset(set(part)):
            print(part)
```

But it doesn't look at the order, as all are string you could simply concat the elements in part and check if `abc` is in

```
value = 'abc'
for sublist in x:
    for part in sublist:
        if value in ''.join(map(str, part)):
            print(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recursively searches regardless of levels of sublists**

Since poster requires:

> this list is dynamic and it can have more than 3 lists inside

```
def find(lst, t, result = None):
  if not isinstance(t, list): # insure t is a list
    t = [t]

  if result is None:  # Set default result
    result = []

  for sublist in lst: # outer list loop
    if isinstance(sublist, list):
      if sublist[:-1] == t:
        result.append(sublist[-1])
        return result
      else:
        find(sublist, t, result) # recursively check sublists

  return result

x = [[['a', 5],
      ['b', 0.11],
      ['c', 0.85]],
     [['a', 'b', 0.5],
      ['b', 'c', 1.0],
      ['c', 'a', 0.7]],
     [['a', 'b', 'c', 0.9],
      ['b', 'c', 'a', 0.4],
      ['a', 'c', 'b', 1.0]],
    [[
      ['a', 'a', 'c', 2],    # additional level added
      ['x', 'a', 5]]]]

print(find(x, 'a'))              # [5]
print(find(x, ['a', 'b']))       # [0.5]
print(find(x, ['a', 'b', 'c']))  # [0.9]
print(find(x, ['a', 'a', 'c']))  # [2]
```

Comment: Yes this can be possible but this list is dynamic and it can have more than 3 lists inside also in that case, I need to add one more for loop in function --  @DarryIG

Comment: @AdityaParikh--updated answer to add arbitrary levels of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = [
        [
            ['a', 5],
            ['b', 0.11],
            ['c', 0.85]
        ],
        [
            ['a', 'b', 0.5],
            ['b', 'c', 1.0],
            ['c', 'a', 0.7]
        ],
        [
            ['a', 'b', 'c', 0.9],
            ['b', 'c', 'a', 0.4],
            ['a', 'c', 'b', 1.0]
        ]
]

# Define search term as string
search = 'abc'
desired_value = None
for collection in x:
    for row in collection:
        # convert everything but the last element in each row to a string for easy comparison
        key = ''.join(row[:-1])
        # if you've found a key matching your search criterion, grab the last value for that row
        if search == key:
            desired_value = row[-1]
            break
```